# Groovy regexes and wildcard permissions

Tags: regex, groovy

Given the following Groovy:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    String permission = "[fizz]:[index]"
    String regex = "[fizz]:[*]"
    if((permission =~ regex).matches()) {
        println "We match!"
    } else {
        println "We don't match!"
    }
}
```

The result is: "*We don't match!*". **How is this possible?!?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape square brackets and, to match `index`, you need to use `.*`, which means "any char, any number of times". Also, groovy's slashy string syntax helps:

```
String permission = "[fizz]:[index]"

String regex = /\[fizz]:\[.*]/

assert (permission =~ regex).matches()

assert permission ==~ regex
```

**Update**: you can use double quote string by escaping square brackets twice:

```
String regex = "\\[fizz]:\\[.*]"
```

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) - how can I accomplish the same but with placing `regex` inside double-quotes? Meaning: `String regex = "???"`   ??

Comment: You don't need to escape the `]`, so `String regex = /\[fizz]:\[.*]/` or `String regex = "\\[fizz]:\\[.*]"` will do :-)